# Why New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment has two very similar parameters ServicePrincipalId and PrincipalId?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am investigating Microsoft Graph powershell module and encountered New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment method. There are two very similar parameters ServicePrincipalId and PrincipalId. All examples that i found use the same value for both parameters. I can not figure out when these params will have different values, maybe someone could help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: The **`ServicePrincipalId`** is the object Id of the Service Principal and the **`PrincipalId`** can be the ID of the user, security group, or service principal that is been granted the role.

The  **`ServicePrincipalId`** and the **`PrincipalId`** is same when you are trying to grant permission to the Service principal like below:

```bash
Connect-MgGraph 

$params = @{
principalId = "ServicePrincipalObjectID"
resourceId = "MicrosoftGraphObjectID"
appRoleId = "5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b"
}

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId ServicePrincipalObjectID -BodyParameter $params
```

*Here the PrincipalType is Service Principal*

[image]

***This script granted `Group.Read.All` API permission to the Service Principal:***

[image]

The **`ServicePrincipalId`** and the **`PrincipalId`** differs when you are granting the app role to the user/group.

```bash
Connect-MgGraph 

$params = @{
principalId = "UserObjectID"
resourceId = "ResourceID"
appRoleId = "AppRoleID"
}

New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId ServicePrincipalObjectID -BodyParameter $params
```

*Here PrincipalType the is User:*

[image]

**The App role granted to the user:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment (Microsoft.Graph.Applications) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/new-mgserviceprincipalapproleassignment?view=graph-powershell-1.0)